# Why are methods like 'center', 'contains' deprecated on Strings?

Tags: groovy

There's the hint to use the CharSequence version.
What's the sense of it? It's anoying to cast every String into a CharSequence.

Regards, Gert

Comment: Did you encounter this on the Katalon IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's telling you it's deprecated?

Don't cast anything, that's just an internal deprecation...  Strings **ARE** CharSequences

This is more a bug in the IDE